# Use query result as parameter to stored procedure in SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that takes a single parameter of data-type XML.

I also have a table that has XML samples which I'd like to test as the parameter for this procedure.

Is it possible to exec the SP and pass the result of a query on the test table as the XML input parameter?  What would the syntax be?

Comment: Do you want to concatenate all the samples into one and send it to procedure or send one by one or something else?

Comment: I just need a single sample at a time into the SP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
declare @myvar xml

select top 1 @myvar=your_xml_column from your_table where your_condition

exec spYourProc @xmlparam=@myvar
```